# Bokeh: how to disable left mouse click scrolling?

Tags: python, bokeh

A basic example of code with empty grid but it can be applied to all figures:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file('test.html')

p = figure(x_range=(0,1), y_range=(0,1), toolbar_location=None)
show(p)
```

When I move mouse cursor while left click left pressed, x and y axis move. In my project, I place figures in the grid but it's annoying that the figures move when I move them with the mouse, I would like the grid to stay still. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Adding (or not adding) specific tools, or specifying which gestures are active by default is all described in the docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools

Comment: Thanks, I searched this but I didn't find the specific page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools

I add this line:

```
p.toolbar.active_drag = None
```